# Unable to pinpoint the error on SQL statement

Tags: sql

I have issued the SQL statement below :

```
SELECT GATNR    
      ,GITNO    
      ,GBANO    
      ,MAX (CASE WHEN GATID = 'GR' THEN GATVN ELSE NULL END) AS GR  
      ,MAX (CASE WHEN GATID = 'SZ' THEN GATVN ELSE NULL END) AS SZ  
FROM TABLEA AS X    
INNER JOIN  
(   
   ( 
     SELECT MAX(GATNR)AS GATNR,GBANO    
     FROM TABLEA    
     GROUP BY GBANO 
   )    
   INNER JOIN   
   (
     SELECT *   
     FROM TABLEB    
   ) AS B   
   ON B.TBANO = GBANO   
) AS Y  
ON Y.GATNR = X.GATNR    
WHERE   
  GITNO LIKE 'F%'   
GROUP BY X.GATNR, X.GITNO, X.GBANO
```

For some reason, it failed to run & generated the following error messages:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 13 Incorrect syntax near the keyword
>   'INNER'.
>   Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 16 Incorrect syntax near the
>   keyword 'AS'.

I'm unable to resolve it. Can someone help me to correct the statement ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want something like this:

```
SELECT GATNR    
      ,GITNO    
      ,GBANO    
      ,MAX (CASE WHEN GATID = 'GR' THEN GATVN ELSE NULL END) AS GR  
      ,MAX (CASE WHEN GATID = 'SZ' THEN GATVN ELSE NULL END) AS SZ  
FROM TABLEA AS X    
INNER JOIN  
(SELECT MAX(GATNR)AS GATNR,GBANO    
FROM TABLEA 
GROUP BY GBANO  
) AS C
ON C.GBANO = X.GBANO AND C.GATNR = X.GATNR
INNER JOIN  
TABLEB AS B  
ON B.TBANO = X.GBANO 
WHERE   
  GITNO LIKE 'F%'   
GROUP BY X.GATNR, X.GITNO, X.GBANO
```

It's hard to know without seeing your schema, though.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this:

```
 SELECT MAX(GATNR)AS GATNR,GBANO
```

To:

```
 SELECT MAX(GATNR) AS GATNR,GBANO
```

(I added a space between "MAX(GATNR)" and "AS"). I am not sure if this will fix the query.